# Eclipse Orion, does it not run in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, browser, web, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-orion

Sorry if I am just really dense, but I read the [Top 10 Eclipse Kepler Features](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/06/26/top-10-eclipse-kepler-features/) and I see Orion at #1. It claims to run all in the browser. I find it really interesting, but it looks like a completely separate tool. Am I wrong?

http://www.eclipse.org/orion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not wrong. Eclipse Foundation has grown beyond its initial IDE roots. In addition to the desktop IDE and IDE components, it also plays host to a number of frameworks. Orion is a browser-based development environment, entirely separate from Eclipse the desktop IDE. The only unifying aspect is that the project is hosted by Eclipse Foundation.